Integration Issues with Robotiq FT300 Sensor on Universal Robot in Gazebo (ROS Noetic, Ubuntu 20.04)
I'm currently working on integrating a Robotiq FT300 sensor with a Universal Robot (UR5) in Gazebo using ROS Noetic on Ubuntu 20.04, and I'm encountering some issues that I hope you can help me resolve.
Repositories Used:
Universal Robot: https://github.com/ros-industrial/universal_robot.git
Robotiq Sensor: https://github.com/ros-industrial/robotiq.git
Modifications Made:
I included the FT300 sensor URDF in the ur_description/urdf/inc/ur_macro.xacro file:
<xacro:include filename="$(find robotiq_ft_sensor)/urdf/robotiq_ft300.urdf.xacro" />
Added the sensor to the end-effector in the same file:
<!-- Add the FT300 sensor to the end-effector -->
<xacro:robotiq_ft300 parent="${prefix}tool0" prefix="">
  <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
</xacro:robotiq_ft300>

Current State:
The sensor is physically added correctly and visualized in both RViz and Gazebo.
When trying to move the robot in RViz, the robot does not move in Gazebo, likely due to collision issues.
Issues:
Warnings:
IK plugin for group 'manipulator' relies on deprecated API. Please implement initialize(RobotModel, ...).
Unable to find a valid state nearby the start state.
START_STATE_IN_COLLISION
Actions Taken:
Added the following to the URDF to disable collisions:
<disable_collisions link1="tool0" link2="ft300_mounting_plate" reason="Sensor attached to tool"/>
<disable_collisions link1="tool0" link2="ft300_sensor" reason="Sensor attached to tool"/>
<disable_collisions link1="ft300_mounting_plate" link2="ft300_sensor" reason="Sensor assembly"/>
Despite these steps, I still face collision issues, and the robot cannot move in Gazebo.
Questions:
What are the correct steps to properly integrate the FT300 sensor with the UR5 to ensure it moves correctly in Gazebo?
How can I resolve the collision warnings and ensure the robot can move as expected?
Are there specific configurations or parameters that need to be adjusted to accommodate the sensor?
Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
